# Confused by selection.filter

Tags: d3.js

I'm having a hard time understanding `selection.filter`. I tried this, in a blank document:

```
d3.selectAll('rect')
    .data([1, 2, 3])
    .filter(function(d) { return d>1; })

// [ Array[0] ]
```

I expected the selection to have 2 elements, but it has 0. Maybe it's because I'm working with an empty update selection...

```
d3.selectAll('rect')
    .data([1, 2, 3])
  .enter()
    .filter(function(d) { return d>1; })

// []
```

Now it seems I don't even have a selection.

If the DOM elements exist

```
d3.selectAll('rect').data([1, 2, 3])
  .enter().append('rect')
```

and then I select and filter

```
d3.selectAll('rect').filter(function(d) { return d>1; })

// [ Array[2] ]
```

it seems to work. So what's going on here? Filter seems to work in [this example](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4063269#file-index-html-L31) on selections that don't correspond to any DOM elements, so I'd expect it to work in my first example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.filter()` function only works on selections that have data bound to them already, i.e. not after you've called `.data()` on them. The example you've linked to doesn't actually work the way it seems to do -- let me reindent for clarity:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
    .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; })
  )
  .enter().append("g")
```

The `.filter()` function isn't actually applied to a selection here, but to the array that `bubble.nodes()` returns. This is then passed to `.data()`. And this is exactly what you would do in a case like yours -- there's no need to filter the selection if you can filter the data that determines it.

Comment: Tricky! Thanks so much Lars. This is what I typically do, I just saw this example and wanted to do things idiomatically.

Comment: No problem, the indentation in that example is very misleading.